# creating different screens in a GUI game on a canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is what I have so far, I am making a game where you have a character (right now it is just a circle) and you have to make it through the game without touching the walls. It will progressively get harder as you can see the first level you wouldn't have to really even do much. What I don't know how to do is create a "Start screen with the game title and a start button as well as a instructions button while still being a 600x600 canvas. I've looked around and there are frames and classes being used in most situations but I also read somewhere you shouldn't use .pack with .grid? If anyone could give me an idea how to just even make one screen I'm sure I could piece the rest together and it would be greatly appreciated!

```
from Tkinter import *


'''global for all three levels'''

root=Tk()
root.wm_title("Game title")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg = 'white')
canvas.grid()

circle = canvas.create_oval(280, 280, 300, 300, fill = 'purple')
dx, dy = 0, 0

def move(e):
    global dx, dy
    if e.keysym == 'Left':
        dx, dy = -5, 0
    elif e.keysym == 'Right':
        dx, dy = 5, 0
    elif e.keysym == 'Up':
        dx, dy = 0, -5
    elif e.keysym == 'Down':
        dx, dy = 0, 5
    elif e.keysym == 's':
        dx, dy = 0,0

def animate():
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle)
    canvas.coords(circle, x1 + dx, y1 + dy, x2 + dx, y2 + dy)
    canvas.after(100, animate)       

root.bind('<Left>', move)
root.bind('<Right>', move)
root.bind('<Up>', move)
root.bind('<Down>', move)
animate()


#class main_Screen()        

#start button, instructions button, want it to be 600x600 same as level screens              



#class levels()

    #def level_One()

        #wall1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 650, 200, fill='#00ff00')
        #wall2 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 400, 650, 600, fill='#00ff00')


    #def level_Two():

        #canvas.create_rectangle(500, 0, 600, 600, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(490, 600, 500, 0, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(400, 90, 490, 360, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(440, 40, 0, 0, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(260, 40, 350, 210, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(60, 90, 210, 240, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 10, 310, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(0, 290, 120, 600, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(400, 600, 440, 410, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(440, 410, 270, 500, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(490, 360, 220, 260, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(220, 260, 170, 560, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(170, 560, 210, 240, fill = '#000000')
        #canvas.create_rectangle(350, 560, 220, 550, fill = '#000000')



    #def level_Three()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am also not very keen on how classes work in coding, or how you know what to put. Sorry I am a newbie but any comments help!

Comment: Do you want the start screen to be a separate window? Create an instance of `Toplevel`. Otherwise, create a `Frame` and put whatever you want in the frame.

Comment: I don't want a separate window I want it to just use the same one but then be able to open different screens, and I tried to inout the Toplevel but couldn't seem to get it to work. I will try again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following code as a basis for using different 'screens' in your game. Basically, you stack all of the frames you want to use on top of each other, and then use the command `frame.tkraise()` on the frame that you want to be visible.

```
import Tkinter as tk  # Import the Tkinter library
root = tk.Tk()

top_level_container = tk.Frame(root)  # Set up the null top level container
top_level_container.pack()

# These are where you delcare all of the frames you wish to switch between
main_frame = tk.Frame(top_level_container)
game_frame = tk.Frame(top_level_container)

# Stack all of these frame on top of each other
for frame in (main_frame, game_frame):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news', padx=0, pady=0)


def switch_main():  # Bring the main frame to the front
    main_frame.tkraise()


def switch_game():  # Bring the game frame to the front
    game_frame.tkraise()

switch_main()  # Start with the main frame in front

# Create the contents of the main frame
main_text = tk.Label(main_frame, text="This is the main screen")
main_text.pack()
main_button = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Switch screens",
                        command=switch_game, background="blue")
main_button.pack()

# Create the contents of the game frame
game_text = tk.Label(game_frame, text="This is the game screen")
game_text.pack()
game_button = tk.Button(game_frame, text="Switch screens",
                        command=switch_main, background="green")
game_button.pack()

root.mainloop()  # Execute the main event handler
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry this is belated but I decided to keep it all one screen and just clear the canvas each time.

Comment: No worries, just a warning though, if you need things to update at any high frequency, you may find that clearing and redrawing each time will slow you down. If it's just occasionally though than that method should be fine.

Comment: Yeah since I only have three levels I figured it shouldn't affect it too much :)